# Looking for a x-, y- and z-axis gridview solution

Tags: asp.net, tabular

I've been asked to come up with a way of showing a 3-axis gridview and wondered if anyone else had solved this problem or knows of a site that has managed to?

Let me try and explain further...

I currently have two sets of data that are easily represented in a normal table, via columns and rows.

```
            Option A    Option B    Option C

Option 1    xxx.xx      xxx.xx      xxx.xx

Option 2    xxx.xx      xxx.xx      xxx.xx

Option 3    xxx.xx      xxx.xx      xxx.xx
```

I now have a third set of data - say Option i, Option ii, Option iii - which will result in 27 values instead of the 9 from the 2-D grid above.

I need a really simple way of viewing this info and also making the HTML semantically correct behind the scenes.

Has anyone else had this problem and come up with a good solution to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd also posted this on another Stack Exchange 1.0 site - http://uxexchange.com/ and got an answer here:

http://uxexchange.com/questions/3598/looking-for-a-x-y-and-z-axis-gridview-solution

I hope this helps others.

Sniffer